# Visual Studio 2015 not showing Project Templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I don't know why all of a sudden my VS 2015 stopped showing Templates list even if i try to open a old project with VS 2015 it doesn't shows anything.

Tried uninstalling and installing VS 2015 again, still no luck.

[image]

Kindly help me to fix this...

Comment: You haven't select any programming areas before installation?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457348.aspx

Comment: i had selected default installation, which worked last time.